# Overload each method with order

Tags: ruby

I have an erb template which generates the config file for an httpd.

It's important that a particular location is written last (it is a catch all)

At the moment the code looks like

```
cluster.apps.each do |app|
  # Render config
end
```

I'd like to overload the each method on the apps object to guarantee order. What's the best place to start looking for how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to overload it, you can do something like

```
class Cluster
  #..code

  def each_application
    return unless block_given? #ensure a block was given
    a = @apps.shift #Implement this to grab the element you want
    @apps.each{|x| yield x}
    yield a  #yield the element that you want last
  end
end
```

So you can now do:

```
cluster.each_application do |app|
  #Render config
end
```

And with the current implementation above, it will yield all the elements(except the first one) in a row. The last yielded item is the first one that was shifted off.

Comment: This is so much better than the kludge that I came up with. Thanks!