# How do I overload ***each*** to establish an desired ordering

Tags: ruby, each, overloading, enumerator

This is similar to question posted in [Overload each method with order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710018/overload-each-method-with-order/9005541#9005541) but with the difference that I would like to have all associated *enumerable* methods supported without redefinition.

Using a mixin, how do I override ***each*** and all associated methods supplied by enumerable without redefining each of them. For example:

```
module Ordering
   def self.included base
       base.class_eval do
           alias_method :old_each,:each

           def each *args,&block
               reverse.old_each(*args,&block) # sample: just reverse std order
           end
       end
   end
end

class OrderedArray < Array
   include Ordering
end

a=OrderedArray.new [1,2,3]
a.each{|_| p _} # works nicely
p a.collect     # fails!
```

generates:

```
3
2
1
[1, 2, 3]
```

Redefining ***each*** doesn't seem to have redefined ***collect!***

Comment: Looks like `Enumerable#collect` is overridden in `Array` with its own implementation that doesn't honor `each` method.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to override the comparison operator (`<=>`) to have it return the same ordering , and also `include Enumerable` in your class.

Comment: `Enumerable` module is already included into `Array`. And `<=>` is necessary only for methods like `min` or `sort`.

Comment: @AShelly & @-KL-7: While my supplied example is specializing ***each*** to revise default ordering... it might be desirable to apply an _implicit_ filtering (i.e. drop all *nil* entries).  Again I wouldn't want to redefine all _enumeration_ methods.

Comment: Overriding `each` and `<= ` should be sufficient to give most classes all the enumeration methods.   Your example class , which derives from `Array`, seems to be different, because Array has custom implementations of some of these methods that bypass `each`.  (Probably for optimization purposes).  Perhaps you could try Delegating Array instead of inheriting from it.